# can I have more than one route per action on select parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

my action has two 3 parameters, but only two are called at a time. So I want to do this:
People is the action, string Height, string searchHigh, sting searchLow

```
 /Groups/People/Tall/searchHigh
```

and this

```
 /Groups/People/Short/searchLow
```

i map both and the first route works, but the second gets appended to the first when go to the short tab.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the action with only two params, and inside the action you would check if the 1st param is either "short" or "tall" and set your params accordingly:

```
 public ActionResult People(string Height, string measurementLimit)
    {
    string searchHigh, searchLow;

    if (Height == "Tall")
       searchHigh = measurementLimit;
    else
       searchLow = measurementLimit;
//Rest of your code

    }
```

Not as elegant as having the route assign the parameters, but it should work.

Hope it helps.